# Insert StringBuilder sb.ToString() which is a JSON value to the SQL Server database table?

Tags: c#, .net, json, sql-server, stringbuilder

I have a typical JSON format which I have returned using stringbuilder and stored as `sb.ToString()`.

I want this data of `sb.ToString()` to be inserted to a new table in my database in SQL Server.

Below is the  format of JSON in `sb.ToString()`:

```
{"Metadata": [{"Key":"FirstName","Value": "ABC"},
{"Key":"LastName","Value": "XYZ"},
{"Key":"Age","Value": "33"},],
{"Metadata": [{"Key":"FirstName","Value": "PQR"},
{"Key":"LastName","Value": "LMN"},
{"Key":"Age","Value": "55"},]
```

I want to take the above data and insert this into a SQL Server new table with columns as(Key) **FirstName**, **LastName** and **Age** whereas rows as respective (Value) ABC, XYZ, 33 in first row and thereafter other values to the next row from the JSON.

I have programmed in C# so it would be of great help if someone gets the logic in C#.

Comment: The JSON in the question is not valid  and what is your SQL Server version?

Comment: There are loads of tutorials out there on how to access SQL Server from C#. Please do some research, have a go, and then when you get stuck ask a specific question.

Comment: @Zhorov, this is the customized json data which is created dynamically using stringbuilder and this format i want to just take Key as columns and append values to rows in a table

Comment: @DaleK, I know how to access SQL Server from C#, My question is the fomat which I have given,  how do I insert that sort of string to a table.

Comment: I don’t understand. If you build the JSON yourself, you must already have the values for FirstName, LastName and Age. So why would you need to extract them from your (invalid) JSON in order to insert them into FirstName, LastName and Age columns?

Comment: can I check: do you just want to insert the string *as is* into a single column? or do you want to split it into different columns following the keys/values?

Comment: side note: storing key/value pairs like this in JSON is horrible - JSON is *already* a key/value system, so it is preferable to just use: `{"Age": 55, "LastName": "LMN"}` etc; and it is rarely a good idea to build JSON by hand - there are a *lot* of edge cases; just about any JSON serializer would be preferable to hand-coding it

Comment: @MarcGravell, Either of them will do, even if a single string is aaded to a column with id will do or else split into different column is complex I know but if it can be done then okay. Also I know it is not good idea to store json like key value but since I am working with an API, It demands this format to accepted.

Comment: if you just want to store the string; it doesn't *matter* that it is json - you're really just asking "how do I store a string in SQL Server" - which is a 2-second google search (personally I'd just use Dapper: `conn.Execute("insert TheTable (TheColumn) values (@value)", new { value });`)

Comment: To echo MarcGravell, as you already know how to access SQL Server, what particular part about inserting a string into a table don't you know how to do?

Comment: @MarcGravell this is completed. I stored the json into a string and appended it to a textfile and thereafter parsed and edited out it into the proper json and put the stirng into variable followedby creating a table. Thanks for the kind assistance.

Comment: @DaleK I know how to do it maybe I failed to elaborate the things in detail.